# Shorter way to return a variable if it exists in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is this a shorter, more elegant, more DRY way to write this in Ruby?

```
if first_variable
   first_variable # return variable if it exists
else
   second_variable # otherwise, return something else
end
```

Or this?

```
if first_variable
   first_variable.method_name 
else
   second_variable
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your two examples are semantically different, so I'll only give an example of the first.

```
return first_variable || second_variable
```

Your second example returns the result of a method call if first_variable is not nil.  This is different than your first example, so I don't understand comparing them.  I also don't understand your use of DRY.  You are not repeating yourself in either case.  Why does an if statement bother you so much?  This is not the stuff you should be worrying about.

Comment: `return first_variable || second_variable` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly wondering if there was a way to avoid writing "first_variable" twice. I am working on an application where I am checking to see if a lot of variables exist, and then returning it if does. Some of those variable names exist. It just seemed like there was a more elegant way to do it. Or that there might something similar to ampersand+colon(&:) shortcut.

Comment: Ok, I removed the second example.  I only use Ruby for simple scripts, I am not really a "rubyist".  I try to learn the Ruby way to do things, but it is not one of my primary languages, so I'm not always up to speed on common idioms.

Comment: Can you use ``or`` instead?

Comment: @KieranAndrews: You can.  You should be aware however that `or` has lower precedence than `||`.  They both short circuit.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work: https://gist.github.com/TigerWolf/e4b946473258c6f62075 Looks like they need to be expressions.

Comment: @KieranAndrews: That is odd, and so is this: `def bar; nil or true; end;` is fine and works as expected.  I honestly don't know what the difference is, and I'm watching a movie, so can't check the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby also supports the ternary operation known from C:

```
return first_variable ? first_variable.method_name : second_variable
```

Another possibility is to write the usual "if" version on one line, which feels more like natural language:

```
return if first_variable then first_variable.method_name else second_variable end
```

Comment: I prefer the ternary version. There is better visual separation of the value being returned making it easier to see what is happening. Functionally they are the same, but maintenance-wise the first is easier to grok.

Answer (score 1):

Using `||` is the only syntax that is DRY using basic Ruby. However this won't work:

- if you want to reject `var1` when it's in a truthy state, e.g. `""`
- if you want to keep `var1` when it's in a falsy state, e.g. `false` (which is different for your purposes to `nil`)

In short if your aim is to check whether `var1` is *present*, **you will have to repeat yourself with some kind of `var1.check ? var1 : var2` syntax**. (`check` isn't a real method – I'm using that to mean whatever check you want to do on it to ensure it's present for your app's purposes.)

The [Demand](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-demand) gem which I wrote gets around this and allows a DRY syntax:

```
return demand(var1, var2)
```

This checks whether `var1` is present and returns it if so. Otherwise, it returns `var2`.

Comment: The first exception you mention can be solved by using the `presence` method: `var1.presence || var2`
This works because `presence` returns the value of var1 if `var1.present?` is `true`, and `nil` otherwise.